# move down of values of textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I have 'n' number of divs. If I click add button created new div last and values are move to next div, so that time first div is empty. How to perform this one using jquery?

```
<div>
    <div id='mydiv1'><textarea id='mytask1'>hai</textarea></div>
    <div id='mydiv2'><textarea id='mytask2'>hai1</textarea></div>
    ..................
    ........................
    <div id='mydiv8'><textarea id='mytask8'>hai2</textarea></div>
    <div id='mydiv9'><textarea id='mytask9'>hello</textarea></div>
</div>
```

I have to change this div to

```
<div>
    <div id='mydiv1'><textarea id='mytask1'></textarea></div>
    <div id='mydiv2'><textarea id='mytask2'>hai</textarea></div>
    <div id='mydiv3'><textarea id='mytask3'>hai1</textarea></div>
    ..................
    ........................
    <div id='mydiv9'><textarea id='mytask9'>hai2</textarea></div>
    <div id='mydiv10'><textarea id='mytask10'>hello</textarea></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) would be a better approach:

```
i = i+1;  //maintain counter properly.
$("<div id='mydiv"+i+"'><textarea id='mytask"+i+"'></textarea></div>").insertBefore( "<div id='mydiv"+(i-1)+"'><textarea id='mytask"+(i-1)+"'></textarea></div>" );
```

So you will get a sequence like:

```
mydiv9
mydiv8
mydiv7
.
.
mydiv1
```

**EDIT:**

If the ids are not in correct order, then you can go with [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$("#parentDiv").prepend($("<div id='"+div_id+"'><textarea id='"+task_id+"'></textarea></div>"))
```

[A jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLnyzrcp/2/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: if i use prepend a new dive added first part of parent div.but values are not move down